# send and receive data without reloading page in flask

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask, sqlalchemy, python-requests

i have a flask app and i'm trying to rebuild it and make the app functional without having to reload the page
the working scheme for now with reloading

```
@app.route('/ITMODE/Cases/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def Cases():
        if Session.get('user_id') is None or Session['dept_id']!=1:
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
            
        else:
            session = DBSession()
            connUser=session.query(User).filter(User.id==Session.get('user_id')).one()
            session.close()
            if request.method == 'GET':
                session = DBSession()
                status= session.query(Req_Status.Status_name)
                session.close()
                return render_template('DefaultAdmin.html', title='All User Cases', conn=connUser,St=status)
            else:
                Status = request.form.get('Status')
                session = DBSession()                
                status= session.query(Req_Status.Status_name)
                    UserRequests= session.query(Requests).filter_by(Status_Name=Status).order_by(desc(Requests.Record_Created)).all()              
                    session.close()
                return render_template('DefaultAdmin.html', title='All User Cases',conn=connUser, rows=UserRequests,St=status)
```

the data after post request should be printed in HTML table
Table#1

```
{% for row in rows %}
<tr >
    <td>ITReq#{{ row.id }} 
    </td>
    <td>{{ row.name }}<br></td>        
    <td>{{ row.Record_Created }}</td>
    <td class="mul">{{ row.Description }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.Assigned_To }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.Status_Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.Type_Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.Priority_Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.Time_To_Solve }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.UNIT_Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.FirstResponseAt }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.ResolvedAt }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

the scheme i'm working on :

```
       if request.method == 'POST':
            rf = request.form
            for key in rf.keys():
                Status = key.strip('"')
            session = DBSession()
            status = session.query(Req_Status.Status_name)
            UserRequests = session.query(Requests).filter(Requests.Status_Name==Status).order_by(desc(
                Requests.Record_Created)).all()
            session.close()
            print(Status)
            dic=[]
            for r in UserRequests:
                dic+=({'id':r.id},{'name':r.name},{'Record_Created':r.Record_Created},{'FirstResponseAt':r.FirstResponseAt},{'ResolvedAt':r.ResolvedAt},{'Description':r.Description}
                      ,{'Assigned_To':r.Assigned_To},{'Status_Name':r.Status_Name},{'Type_Name':r.Type_Name},{'Priority_Name':r.Priority_Name},{'User_ID':r.User_ID},{'OpenedToPending':r.OpenedToPending}
                      ,{'PendingToSolved':r.PendingToSolved},{'ResolvedAt':r.ResolvedAt})
            return jsonify({'UserStatus': Status},dic )
```

Now I can get data from html to flask using jquery
but i can't process the jsonify to get the data in table as in Table#1
i tried to make this call draw the table but to no hope

```
req = $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url:'/ITMODE/Cases/',
                  data: selecteStatus,
                  dataType: 'json'
                  
                  })
                  .done(function(data) {    
                    /*data = JSON.stringify(data)
                    for(var key in data){
                      alert('data is ' +data[key]);
                    }*/
                      $.each(data[1], function(index, value) 
                      { var table = $('<table>')/*.addClass('foo')*/;
                        var row = $('<tr>');
                          $('<td>').text('ITReq#'+value.id),
                          $('<td>').text(value.name),
                            $('<td>').text(value.Record_Created),
                              $('<td>').text(value.Description).addClass('mul'),
                        table.append(row);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out
Instead of using the dict as key value pairs i had to group each row so
I made each Raw as  single value then iterated on its values with js